# cakePHP httpSocket is not making post requests

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Here is the action that I call:

```
public function request_add(){

    // remotely post the information to the server
    $link =  "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->webroot.'rest_events.json';


    $data = null;
    $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $data['Event']['customer_id'] = '107';
    $data['Event']['user_id'] = '124';
    $data['Event']['date'] = '2014-07-12';

    $data = array('Event'=>'id');

    $response = $httpSocket->post($link, $data );
    $this->set('response_code', $response->code);
    $this->set('response_body', $response->body);

    $this -> render('/Client/request_add');
}
```

in this case the link is: `http://localhost/application/rest_events.json`

The problem is that the GET request is made instead of POST, and what I get is list of events.

Has anyone faced such a problem before?

I look forward to hearing some opinions.

**UPDATE**

While debugging the http request, I have found that the POST request is made rather than GET. Here is the object:

```
array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'uri' => array(
        'host' => '*****',
        'port' => '*****',
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'user' => null,
        'pass' => null,
        'path' => '/application/rest_events.json',
        'query' => array(),
        'fragment' => null
    ),
    'version' => '1.1',
    'body' => 'Event%5Bcustomer_id%5D=107&Event%5Buser_id%5D=124&Event%5Bdate%5D=2014-07-12',
    'line' => 'POST /application/rest_events.json HTTP/1.1
',
    'header' => 'Host: localhost
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 76
',
    'raw' => 'POST /application/rest_events.json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 76

Event%5Bcustomer_id%5D=107&Event%5Buser_id%5D=124&Event%5Bdate%5D=2014-07-12',
    'redirect' => false,
    'cookies' => array(),
    'proxy' => array(),
    'auth' => array()
)
```

But still the `index()` action is being called instead of `add()`. So the problem is in routing. Am I right?

Comment: Have you actually tested whether it's really a GET request? Maybe CakePHP just couldn't identify it as POST for whatever reason. In any case there's not enough details for anything other than guessing. Check `HttpSocket::$request` (after issuing the request) on the "client" side, and `php://input` and `$_SERVER` on the "server" side.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Well what happens is that the `index()` action is called instead of `add()`. 
When I try to check `HttpSocket::$request` on the client side, I get the following error: `Access to undeclared static property`.

When should I look for `php://input` and `$_SERVER`?

If there is any information that I could provide, just let me know.

Comment: I didn't wanted to say that you should access it statically, sorry, that's just how you write it when describing an API. Of course you'll have to actually access it on the object instance as the property isn't static, ie `$httpSocket->request`. For now it doesn't matter when you access `php://input` and `$_SERVER`, the necessary data should be available immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me to debug! That really helped, and as you can see in the question update, the request is actually POST. So the error is routing? Could you provide your suggestions as an answer?
And could you please help to figure out the problem that has actually been found:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754365/