# CakePHP mapping HTTP request to the correct action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have been trying to set up RESTful functionality in my app and I face a problem of whatever action I call it is router to that particular controllers `index` action. I have been trying to call `add` and `view` actions, but they are just not being routed properly. Here is the resposne I get when trying to call the view action:

```
{"code":404,"url":"\/application\/rest_customers\/54.json","name":"Action RestCustomersController::54() could not be found."}
```

And here is the way it is all set up in. `RestCustomersController`:

```
class RestCustomersController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Customer');
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
    }

    public function view($id=null){

    $customer = $this->Customer->find('first', array(
          'conditions'=>array('Customer.id'=> $id)));

        $this->set(array(
            'customer' => $customer,
            '_serialize' => array('customer')
        )); }}
```

Here are the routes:

```
Router::mapResources('customers');
Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml', 'csv', 'pdf');
```

And here os the `AppControllers` beforeFitler function:

```
if(in_array($this->params['controller'], array('rest_customers'))){
    $this->Auth->allow();
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('add','index', 'view');
}else{
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('add', 'edit');
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
}}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating REST routes for a controller named `Customers`, but you are actually accessing a controller named `RestCustomers`, so what you are experiencing is the expected behavior as there simply are no REST routes connected for the `RestCustomers` controller.

You should either rename your controller to `CustomersController`, or change your mapping to use the correct name so that it will connect the routes to `RestCustomersController`

```
Router::mapResources('rest_customers');
```

Comment: Well, I have followed this tutorial: http://miftyisbored.com/complete-restful-service-client-cakephp-tutorial/

That is how ended up having the previous code. But your suggestion works as it should! Thanks alot.